# Qt - Cannot get lambda to work

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda

I have the following function, in which I want to prune my `std::set<QString> words` from words longer/shorter than `main_word` by more than 4 characters.

```
void Cluster::prune(QString main_word)
{
    words.erase(std::remove_if(words.begin(),
                               words.end(),
                               [=](QString w){return std::abs(main_word.length() - w.length()) > 4;}),
                words.end());
}
```

I get the following error while building:

```
d:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1176: błąd: passing 'const QString' as 'this' argument of 'QString& QString::operator=(const QString&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
             *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
                       ^
```

I'm a bit confused - what am I doing wrong with this lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the erase remove-if idiom on sets - because a `set<K>` internally contains elements of type `const K` - they're nonmodifiable and [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) requires the objects to be MoveAssignable.

You'll have to use a loop:

```
for (auto it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); /* nothing */)
{
    if (std::abs(main_word.length() - it->length()) > 4) {
        it = words.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like charm, thanks! So this lambda should work with vector, right?

Comment: @pkrysiak Right. Except in that case, I would suggest improvements to your lambda: both `main_word` and `w` should be taken by reference. As is, you're taking lots of extra copies.